# Third Party API Url is working on browser but there is issue at Telnet - ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, telnet, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I have asp.net mvc application where there is API call of third party application to get the status through HTTPWebRequest Class.

API Url is opening fine on browser but API Url and IP is not working when we call it through application or making telnet request on 443 port.

Answer (score 0):

Broswer only can send `GET` request, so please check your `HTTPWebRequest` method.

I suggest use `HttpHelper`, you can [refer my somple code in github](https://github.com/Jason446620/core2.0-/blob/master/coreUtils/Common/HttpHelper.cs). You just make sure you can access the api in broswer or postman, then my sample code will work fine.